# I want to import faker module in python but i can'ta do

Tags: python, import, pip, faker

I am using python 3.8.2 and I have installed pip install Faker but also I can't do

[image: rt]

Comment: you may have two Pythons installed and you installed module for one Python but juputer may use other Python. Every Python need own module. You can check versions `pip -V` and `python -V`. If you run juputer `python -m juputer` then you can also try `python -m pip install ...`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). In general, code/errors/data in text format >>>> code/errors/data as an image >> nothing. Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Answer (score 0):

Your Jupyter Notebook is having problem with path. There might be different versions installed on your system. I had the same issue. You can take help of this article[ImportError: No module named ‘XYZ’](https://towardsdatascience.com/importerror-no-module-named-xyz-45e4a5339e1b)